Set Monday instead of Sunday as first column in @nextui-org/react Calendar
How can I set the Calendar to have Monday instead of Sunday, as the first day of the week?
<Calendar
    aria-label="Date (Show Month and Year Picker)"
    defaultValue={someVariableName}
    focusedValue={someVariableName}
    onFocusChange={(focused: CalendarDate) => {
        handleEdit("someVariableName", focused);
    }}
    showMonthAndYearPickers
/>

I have tried, though unfortunately it didn't work:
<Calendar
    aria-label="Date (Show Month and Year Picker)"
    locale="en-GB"
    defaultValue={someVariableName}
    focusedValue={someVariableName}
    onFocusChange={(focused: CalendarDate) => {
        handleEdit("someVariableName", focused);
    }}
    showMonthAndYearPickers
/>

